# Plugin for an existing plugin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, plugin, magento2.3.5-p2, after-plugin

Is it possible to create a plugin for an existing plugin class in Magento 2.3.5-p2 and if so, are there any special ways of doing this besides the normal plugin creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes It's Possible possible to create a plugin for an existing plugin class .

**The sortOrder property from the plugin node declared in di.xml determines the plugin’s prioritization when more than one plugin is observing the same method.**

**like this**

```
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_plugina" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\PluginA" sortOrder="10" />
        <plugin name="vendor_module_pluginb" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\PluginB" sortOrder="20" />
        <plugin name="vendor_module_pluginc" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\PluginC" sortOrder="30" />
    </type>
</config>
```

[For More Click Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#prioritizing-plugins)